# onsubmit check if checked and change source

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, onsubmit

this doesn't seem to work, and resets checked...would like to only update if checked

```html
<iframe id="time" name="time" type="text/html" src="http://time.is/"></iframe>

<form id="url" onsubmit="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="target" id="target" value="http://time.is" size="40"></form>

<input type="checkbox" name="check1" />
```

```js
$('.url').submit {
    if($('input[name="check1"]', this).is(':checked')) {
        document.getElementById(time).src = url;
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/57/

Comment: You should post code here and be more descriptive or you are likely to be downvoted. Remember that this site is also an archive for anyone experiencing your similar problem and that won't happen if the fiddle expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

1.you need to add submit button inside html form (or have a way to trigger form submission with JavaScript), something like this:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

2.the varible `url` is undefined, you may add the following line in the JavaScript

```
var url = $('#target').val();
```

3.

```
document.getElementById(time).src = url;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('time').src = url;
```

4.change the first line of script from

```
$('.url').submit {
```

to

```
$('#url').submit(function() {
```

5.as Trinh Hoang Nhu said, check box should be inside form because you are using

```
if ($('input[name="check1"]', this)...
```

Here's the [updated test](http://jsfiddle.net/su__/hzSBW/1/)

Comment: will there be any major differences just using onSubmit rather than a Submit Query?

Comment: onsubmit="" in your code doesn't do anything, you can remove it and your code will still work

Comment: the code you put inside onsubmit would execute when a form is submitted. Submit button is one of the possible ways to trigger the form submission.

Comment: In your current code, you don't have a way to trigger form submission. (The only time the form is submitted is when the page is first loaded, because you have $('.url').submit in your code, but that is only called once). There's no way to resubmit the form after you change the url in the input box. That is what Submit button for (you can use Submit button to resubmit the form).

Answer (score 1):

Because you put check box out side the form but in code you call `if ($('input[name="check1"]', this).is(':checked')) {` should move check box inside form and also remove `onsubmit=""`

```
<div class="c">
   <iframe id="time" name="time" type="text/html" src="http://time.is/" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<form id="url" method="post" target="time">
   <div>
      <input type="text" name="target" id="target" value="http://time.is" size="40">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check1" />
   </div>
</form>

<script>
   $(function(){
       $('#url').submit (function(){
          if ($('input[name="check1"]', this).is(':checked')) {
            document.getElementById('time').src = url;
          } else {
            alert('no');
          }
          return false;
       });
   });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZZe5X/66/

Comment: i finally got this to work server side by
function check (url) {
$('#url').submit(function() {
    if ($('input[name="check1"]', this).is(':checked')) {
        var url = $('#target').val();
        document.getElementById('time').src = url;
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
    return false;
});
}

<body onload="check('url')">